# Rounded result, how to make proper operations in Angular?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a kind of rounded result of this operation:

```
$scope.pay_holiday_days = (parseInt($scope.reached_holiday_days) + pending_holiday_days) * $scope.daily_base_salary;
```

Supposing that I have  (333.33)*15 = (the result should be: 4 999.95)

But insted of that I get a result of (5000), closed.

Not using toFixed or any similar function, and in the console apppears the same number (5000)

Comment: Try parseFloat() instead of parseInt()

Comment: Thanks. I tested parseFloat, and nay, nothing different happens.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, could you create an [mcve] using [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n53tqeza/6/) (or add a runnable snippet to your post)?